# .htaccess changes my REQUEST_METHOD in api

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, url

My API works fine if I include "/" at the end of the url without modifying the REQUEST METHOD. But if I remove "/" at the end of the URL I always get GET.
This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ - [L]    
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I need the REQUEST METHOD to not change since I make decisions in my code based on that.

Comment: "My API works fine if I include "/" at the end of the url" - But if you include a trailing slash on the URL, neither of the two rules you've posted would do anything since the regex won't match. (?)

Comment: "if I remove "/" at the end of the URL I always get GET." - If the URL you are requesting maps to a filesystem directory then mod_dir will trigger a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash - if the user-agent follows the redirect then yes, it will indeed be converted to a GET request. But you've not stated the URL(s) being requested and your filesystem structure. (And if you are requesting a filesystem directory then the rules you've posted are not doing anything. ?)